# UINavigationBar disappears immediately while pushViewcontroller with animated is true

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I am trying to make the navigation bar transparent for one view controller when it shows. It works. However the animation does not seems to be right when I re-enter the view controller again from the parent view controller.

The first time the navigation bar stays and disappear in animated way until the second view fully shows. However, the second time and later, the navigation bar just fully disappears and the second view shows in animation .

I have created a minimum project here to show the problem: https://github.com/zwang/CVNavigationBarTest

Issue Reproducing Step:

1. Click one of the code block in the Colors view controller
2. Click back button
3. Click one of the code block again.
4. See the problem

The first time clicking one of the color blocks in Colors view controller, the animation of transition is good and as expected. However, when clicking one of the color blocks again after coming back from the second view controller, you can notice the navigation bar area immediately becomes black and then the animation of showing the second view controller starts. You can toggle the slow animation in simulator to see the problem more clearly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Another solution I am thinking is to have the two buttons in the second view done in a custom way. And only set the navigation bar transparent. Will try that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution to make the animation looks good. I just change the `backgroundColor` of the window to be `white` given the navigation bar background color is white in my app. Below is the code I added.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return true
}
```

The same solution applies to issue related UITabBar in the similar case too.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to remove the animations when you´re changing the slides. I have had the same issues and this is what I did because I did not find a better solution.

In your ViewController:
Set the `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(colorVC, animated: true)` to `animated false`.

In your ColorViewController:
Override the back button to disable the animation for the back button. So in your viewDidLoad do the following:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New back button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "back:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

And then create the new back function:

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Go back to the previous ViewController without an animation
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
}
```

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m4yxlpydu3c7an/CVNavigationBarTest-master.zip?dl=0) is your project with my updated code that you can download.

Comment: Hi Rashwan, thanks for the answer. I think not doing animation is one option for us. However, we really like to have the animation. I tested without animation before and it does not looks good in the app. So animation is kind of a must for us. Thanks again for the help.